# z-index issue with two divs, one of them with absolute position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My question is very simple, I have two divs, one of them with absolute position. I set the z-index of the absolute position div to the lowest value and the other one with the highest value but always the one with absolute position remains on top (opposite behavior).

Here you have an image:

[image]

Here you have the code:

```
<div style="position:relative;">
    <div style="position:absolute;width:200px;background-color:#ff0;z-index:1;">
          SHOULD BE ON BACK. SHOULD BE ON BACK. SHOULD BE ON BACK.
        SHOULD BE ON BACK. SHOULD BE ON BACK. 
    </div>
    <div style="width:300px;background-color:#0f0;z-index:999999;">
        SHOULD BE ON FRONT. SHOULD BE ON FRONT.
        SHOULD BE ON FRONT. SHOULD BE ON FRONT.
    </div>
</div>
```

Take a look at the following jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rnbd3nek/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get rid of the style in the parent div and add the style into the front div. Add `position:relative` to the 'THIS SHOULD BE ON FRONT'.

Thus:

```
<div>
    <div style="position:absolute;width:200px;background-color:#ff0;z-index:1;">
      SHOULD BE ON BACK. SHOULD BE ON BACK. SHOULD BE ON BACK.
    SHOULD BE ON BACK. SHOULD BE ON BACK. 
    </div>
    <div style="position:relative;width:300px;background-color:#0f0;z-index:999999;">
        SHOULD BE ON FRONT. SHOULD BE ON FRONT.
        SHOULD BE ON FRONT. SHOULD BE ON FRONT.
    </div>
</div>
```

> Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed). 
>    -W3Schools, from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Answer (score 0):

> Add `position: absolute;` for *"SHOULD BE ON FRONT"* element

**Note:** [`z-index`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/) only effects elements that have a [`position`](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/) value other than `static` (the default).

```html
<div style="position:relative;">
    <div style="position:absolute;width:200px;background-color:#ff0;z-index:1;">
       SHOULD BE ON BACK. SHOULD BE ON BACK. SHOULD BE ON BACK.
        SHOULD BE ON BACK. SHOULD BE ON BACK. 
    </div>
    <div style="width:300px;background-color:#0f0;z-index:999999;position:absolute;">
        SHOULD BE ON FRONT. SHOULD BE ON FRONT.
        SHOULD BE ON FRONT. SHOULD BE ON FRONT.
    </div>
</div>
```

### [**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/rnbd3nek/1/)

Comment: Darn, you beat me!

Comment: I need the div on the front has no position:absolute, that's a must for me :(

Comment: @nightclub, You can apply `position:relative;`

Comment: @nightclub Check out my solution :)

Comment: Rayon, make sure to post where the quote is from, w3schools

Comment: @AndrewL, Thanks for the suggestion.. I am not almighty to edit things in milliseconds...

Answer (score 0):

Update your second div to

```
<div style="position:relative;width:300px;background-color:#0f0;z-index:999999;">
    SHOULD BE ON FRONT. SHOULD BE ON FRONT.
    SHOULD BE ON FRONT. SHOULD BE ON FRONT.
</div>
```

Z-index will only ever apply when the DIV has a position set (relative, absolute, fixed etc) - so both divs need a position, not just the one.

Answer (score 0):

Your markup should be like this.

```
<div style="position:relative;">
    <div style="position:absolute;width:200px;background-color:#ff0;z-index:1;">
          SHOULD BE ON BACK. SHOULD BE ON BACK. SHOULD BE ON BACK.
        SHOULD BE ON BACK. SHOULD BE ON BACK. 
    </div>
    <div style="position:relative;width:300px;background-color:#0f0;z-index:2;">
        SHOULD BE ON FRONT. SHOULD BE ON FRONT.
        SHOULD BE ON FRONT. SHOULD BE ON FRONT.
    </div>
</div>
```

Check this updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rnbd3nek/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the first div's z-index to -1,or add the `position:relative` or `position:absolute` to the second div.

Answer (score -1):

Here you go...
Should be in front in not absolute and is in front :P

```
<div style="position:relative;">
  <div style="position:absolute;width:200px;background-color:red;z-index:1;">
    SHOULD BE ON BACK. SHOULD BE ON BACK. SHOULD BE ON BACK. SHOULD BE ON BACK. SHOULD BE ON BACK.
  </div>
  <div style="width:300px;background-color:yellow;z-index:2;position: relative;">
    SHOULD BE ON FRONT. SHOULD BE ON FRONT. SHOULD BE ON FRONT. SHOULD BE ON FRONT.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Make second div position absolute too..

```
<div style="position:absolute;width:300px;background-color:#0f0;z-index:999999;">
```

Final code will look like this

```
<div style="position:relative;">
    <div style="position:absolute;width:200px;background-color:#ff0;z-index:1;">
          SHOULD BE ON BACK. SHOULD BE ON BACK. SHOULD BE ON BACK.
        SHOULD BE ON BACK. SHOULD BE ON BACK. 
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;width:300px;background-color:#0f0;z-index:999999;">
        SHOULD BE ON FRONT. SHOULD BE ON FRONT.
        SHOULD BE ON FRONT. SHOULD BE ON FRONT.
    </div>
</div
```